# JCombobox and JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to work to display a number of jtextfield according to one of the given values in a combobox.

So, I will have a drop down menu with let's say 1 to 4. If the user selects number 3, 3 textfields will be displayed. I've created the jcombobox with a selection of numbers. But I'm not sure how to implement this. If I'm not mistaken I need to use

```
ItemEvent.SELECTED
```

I think I need to create a reference to the JTextField object that will be available to the JComboBox's itemListener object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've added this to my class :

```
// aOption is the combobox I declared 
aOptionComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"1","2","3"})); 

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {

    String num = (String)aOptionComboBox.getSelectedItem(); 
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num);
    JTextField[] textfields = new JTextField[num1];

    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) 
    {
        textfields[i] = new JTextField("Field");
        getContentPane().add(textfields[i]);
        textfields[i].setBounds(200, 90, 100, 25);

    }
}
```

am I on a right track?

Comment: *"am I on a right track?"*  Probably not, if the code uses `setBounds`.  ***Use layouts***.  Also, for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: what happened when you tried it :-) Hint: you probably want to remove any fields that were added earlier. Also: if this is homework, please tag as such

Comment: "Am I on the right track?", the answer to that is Definitely you are on the wrong track. Since inside your for loop, as very much advised to you by @AndrewThompson, not to use **setBounds**. But suppose if you still using it, aren't all the `JTextFields` that you are creating are placed one on top of the other, at the same location. So how come you will see how many are there on your `JFrame` ?

Comment: @GagandeepBali  Huh.. I saw as far as `setBounds` and did not look that bit further.  Great catch.  +1

Answer (score 1):

use the getSelectedItem() on the combobox. This will either yield a string or an integer (depending on how you implemented it). Next use a for-loop to determine the amount of JTextField's and store them in an array.

```
int amount = myJComboBox.getSelectedItem();

JTextField[] textfields = new JTextField[amount];

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
textfields[i] = new JTextField("awesome");
this.add(textfields[i]);
}
```

this way you can easily store the textfields and add them to your panel.

Some added information.

The textfield-array must be accesible outside the eventListener, so you must implement it in your class. that way the whole class can use it.

Comment: I've added this to my class :

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {

        /*aOption is the combobox I declared 
        aOptionComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"1","2","3"})); */

        String num = (String)aOptionComboBox.getSelectedItem(); 
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num);
        JTextField[] textfields = new JTextField[num1];

        for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
            textfields[i] = new JTextField("Field");
            getContentPane().add(textfields[i]);
            textfields[i].setBounds(200, 90, 100, 25);
        }
 }

Comment: @nothingme  Please edit that code into your question (and use code formatting).  It is unreadable at the moment.